# SQL Server vs. Access insert performance, in particular when using GUID

Tags: sql-server, performance, ms-access, guid

I'm interested to know how I could improve the performance of SQL Server when using sequential GUID when using Access 2007 as a front end to SQL Server 2008 (please note it's the only context I'm interested in).

I have made some tests (and gotten some fairly surprising results, in particular from SQL Server when using **sequential** GUID: the insert performance degrades very very quickly and it doesn't seem right to degrade so quickly to me.

Basically the test is as follow:

> *From the Access front-end, using VBA only, insert 100,000 records in batches of 1000,
>   sequentially.*

- I tried it both with a Identity and a sequential GUID as the PK.
- I tried it in *SQL Server 2008 Standard* (no special tweaking just default install) as and an Access 2007 database as the back-end. All tables linked back to the front-end.

Some of the results (more, with raw data available on [my blog entry about the test](http://blog.nkadesign.com/2009/access-vs-sql-server-some-stats-part-1/)):

It's clear that, as the database grows, the insert performance is reduced but SQL Server isn't performing very well at all here.

http://blog.nkadesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/chart02.png

Expanded view of the results for SQL Server:
http://blog.nkadesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/chart03.png

#### Edit 13APR2009

I've found an [issue with my server configuration](http://blog.nkadesign.com/2009/sysadmin-dell-server-performance-madness/) and I updated the [tests on my blog](http://blog.nkadesign.com/2009/access-vs-sql-server-some-stats-part-1/).
Thanks to all for your replies, they helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My question is whether your test setup represents the reality of your application or not. In short, are you testing the right thing?

Is your app going to be appending large numbers of records one at a time?

Or is it going to be appending batches of records based on a SQL SELECT?

If the latter, you might look at trying to do it all server-side, particularly if the source table(s) in the SELECT are on the server. It's important to realize that with ODBC, a batch append is going to be sent to the SQL Server as a single insert for every single row (every similar to the recordset-based approach in your test code). If you move the same process entirely server-side, it can be done as a batch operation.

Also, you should test again using ADO instead of DAO. It may optimize the operation completely differently.

Last of all, someone brought to my attention just this past week this fascinating article by Andy Baron:

[Optimizing Microsoft Office Access Applications Linked to SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb188204.aspx)

I'm still absorbing the contents of that very useful article, and it discusses several issues in regard to non-GUID-specific topics that may help you optimize your process for maximum efficiency.

Comment: For now I'm just trying to understand what affects performance. I initially wanted to test GUID insertion since it's meant to be the most expensive operation. Turns out that the test shows that recordset options are much -much- more important! Thanks for the article, it's going to help me a lot.

Comment: Chosen answer because the link you provided is gold to me.

Comment: It really is quite a good article -- I've bookmarked it and returned to it several times in the last week!

Answer (score 4):

There's two things at play here. First, it's important to point out that SQL doesn't necessarily work very well, for a specific use case, out of the box. It is a professional product designed to be tuned by a person who knows what they're doing.

By comparison, Access is designed to work very well for most use cases without any configuration. The downside of this trade-off is covered in the second point:

SQL Server is designed for scalability. Notice how Access severely degrades with only 100,000 records. It would probably drop very steeply below SQL's line before a million. By comparison, SQL server holds almost perfectly steady, with the variation stabilizing after about 45,000 records and will continue to hold at many millions.

**Edit** I think there also may be something else at play here we're not seeing. I thought your SQL numbers looked bad, so I ran a test of my own. On my desktop running Windows Vista 3.6 ghz and 2gb of RAM, inserts with sequential GUID on SQL Server performed:

- Average of 1382 inserts per second at 0 records
- Average of 1426 inserts per second at 500k records
- Averaging 1609.6 inserts per second from 0 to 500k with an average floor of 992 inserts/sec and an average ceiling of 1989 inserts/sec.

So accounting for the normal variance incurred by running this on an in-use desktop, I'd say SQL Server inserts basically scale linearly from 0 records to half a million. On a dedicated, tuned server I'd expect even more consistency (not to mention *far* better performance):

[Excel chart, inserts per second http://img24.imageshack.us/img24/9485/insertspersecond.jpg](http://img24.imageshack.us/img24/9485/insertspersecond.jpg)

Comment: Hmmm, OK, I agree that SQL Server needs to be tuned but what you say doesn't hold when you're looking at the perf of using GUID: it's degrading too quickly. We're only talking about 100k records here yet I can't insert at more than 66 records/second!

Comment: @Renaud see my revised answer.

Comment: But there's still no way it should be that slow if the transactions are being managed properly.

Comment: @le dorfier that's my point as well, as stated in my edit. There must be something wrong - performance that low is highly suspicious.

Comment: See my further comments in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your results. I'll make a few more tests and report back later.

Comment: Access does not degrade with 100K records unless you fail to design your Access app appropriately.

Comment: @David when does Access start to degrade in your experience?

Comment: We're talking Access front end to SQL Server back end, right? It only degrades if you don't program it correctly -- that can happen with 1000 records. You just have to know which operations to let Jet handle (Jet is very smart) and which ones to move server-side.

Comment: On the other hand, if you're talking about a Jet back end (which wasn't the topic of discussion here), Access still performs very, very well with lots of records assuming the tables are properly indexed and your application is efficient in the way it uses the data.

Comment: I think my new tests help support your view David.

Answer (score 2):

You realize at least part of the decreasing performance is the log filling up, and that a GUID id what, 40 bytes longer than an int?

But I'm not quibbling; it's good to see someone taking actual metrics rather than just handwaving. Modded up.

Comment: Thanks. GUID are in fact 16 bytes. I hadn't thought about the log file but it shouldn't affect performance that badly, especially when there should be no real difference, as far as the log file is concerned, between using and Integer or a GUID, so the issue must come from somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

Where are you getting the data from?

Does it change the numbers if you use the Access Export menu options rather than record-at-a-time-in-a-loop?

VBA is really sensitive to the connection paramters too, and there are lots of options that aren't necessarily intuitive.

If an identity column is acceptable, why are you even considering a sequential GUID (which is something of a tacked-on facility in MSSQL last I checked).

---

EDIT:
Looking at your code and briefly reviewing the Recordset docs on MSDN, I see you may be able to use more efficient parameters. E.g. your dbSeeChanges and dbOpenDynaset, which are appropriate if you are trying to allow for other users messing with the same rows (or needing to get back the inserted IDENTITY value or probably GUID), but I don't think you need those. In essence, after every INSERT or UPDATE, you're reading the record back from the database into VBA. I'd read through those connection config settings carefully, and I bet you'll come up with something a lot more satisfactory.

Comment: the data is created on-the-fly using a simple addnew/update loop on a recordset. connection parameters are simply basic ODBC DSN with default values. I need the GUID for future development (synchronisation over multiple db & occasionally connected clients).

Comment: a. I'd check the GUID insertion issue from @Denis.
b. Then check how you're handling your 1000-row batch transactions. You may not be getting what you expect for transaction control. Have you tried just 1 row per transaction as a worst case?

Comment: Actually, you got something right about the options to the recordset. dbDynaset is mandatory and dbSeeChanges is also mandatory if using an IDENTITY column as PK. What makes performance much better though is to use dbAppendOnly since we don't need to read the record after inserting it.

Comment: I read it that those flags are mandatory if using an IDENTITY *and* you needed to use the recordset after the insert (because otherwise the IDENTITY value wouldn't be populated. But I don't think you need to get it back.

Answer (score 1):

The last time I saw something like that (really slow insertion with GUID PK) was because of the log-file filling up. Insertion performance was dropping like a stone, pretty fast (no hard measurement, just looking at live traces, but it sure looked like it was kinda logarithmic). This was pre-loading of historical data. 
Moved over to identity PK, took care of actually cleaning up the log file, and everything went much better afterwards (a couple of hours where the first version took several hours and was not finished).

Also, just a thought, are there any transactions involved? Maybe SQL Server transactions create a big performance hit that access does not have (given that access is not really geared towards concurrent access).